# How does one quit a stack exchange site completely and not just logging off?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

How does one quit a stack exchange site completely and not just logging off? Any one willing to answer this question?  How do you just delete the the individual sites like biology or english language...you know, the sites that aren't helpful.

Answer (score 4):

There is a help for deleting your account: https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleting-account